# IDE's will not allow my minus sign

Tags: visual-studio, ide, monodevelop, non-ascii-characters

I'm trying to do simple arithmetic:

`Num01 + num02`

`Num01 - num02`

`Num01 * num02`

`Num01 / num02`

But I keep getting an error for the subtraction statement. I've tried with 3 different IDE's now and they all say the exact same error. I'm thinking my - sign has got the wrong ASCII code or something??

Help, it's put the brakes on my learning and making me feel miserable :(

I've never seen anything like this before, usually I install an IDE and off I go.

I've tried Monodevelop, Visual studio code, and Visual studio community.

They all say the same error. I can't remember it exactly word for word and **I'm typing this from my phone at the moment.** But if the compilers accept all the other statements, then why not the minus.

Any help appreciated.
Cheers.

Windows 7 x64

Comment: The minus sign you posted is ASCII code 045, which is the correct code. Do you have any other examples or is there anyway you can get the exact error message?

Comment: I typed the post from my phone, not my computer. I did mention it in the original post, perhaps I should've made it clearer.

Comment: No it was clear, and I did read that because I asked if there is anyway you can get the exact error message. My mistake.

Comment: Are you using a mac?

Comment: Oops should have included that! I'm on Windows 7 x64

Comment: Do you have a numpad on your keyboard as well? Try using that minus and the other minus on this [ASCII Converter](http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/ascii/). For me, they both give me 045, the correct ASCII.

Comment: For what it is worth, `−` this is ASCII 226 136 146. Where as `-` is ASCII 045. The former is technically called the minus sign, whereas the latter is the dash. The dash is what works for me, but I only tested in Notepad++

Comment: Thanks chap! I'll try that first thing tomorrow, as I've got the ball and chain with me now =\

Comment: No problem. You may have to look at your keyboard layout to see if that is the issue. For a workaround, type Alt+45 and that will give you a minus sign, of you can copy and paste this `-`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

So initially I tried what was discussed, but the `-` I'm using is also ASCII code 45. So, I cut and pasted the other `−` (ASCII 226 136 146), and that didn't work either...

The original code in question is:

```
Console.WriteLine(num01 + " + " + num02 + " = " + num01 + num02);
Console.WriteLine(num01 + " - " + num02 + " = " + num01 - num02); // This line gives an error
Console.WriteLine(num01 + " * " + num02 + " = " + num01 * num02);
Console.WriteLine(num01 + " / " + num02 + " = " + num01 / num02);
```

Error CS0019: Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'double' (CS0019)

So it made me think about BODMAS, and what if I enclose the sums in brackets first, so I rewrote the code to:

```
Console.WriteLine(num01 + " + " + num02 + " = " + (num01 + num02));
Console.WriteLine(num01 + " - " + num02 + " = " + (num01 - num02));
Console.WriteLine(num01 + " * " + num02 + " = " + (num01 * num02));
Console.WriteLine(num01 + " / " + num02 + " = " + (num01 / num02));
```

And now it works!

I've no idea why it allowed the other operators but not the minus, but enclosing them in brackets solved it.

Thanks for the help Loaf!
=)